# Strange margin/padding effect when hovering over menu

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

My question is simple really;

http://minimalito.be/ltripple/

As you decrease screen size, the little menu at the top right disappears and a small icon appears. When you click it, another menu will unfold, but as it unfolds there is a small peace 'missing', just click it and you'll see what I mean.

And I have no idea why...I think it's a margin/padding issue, i've tried so many things, but can't seem to find it. It's one of the few problems before it's finished, so it's driving me crazy because I can't find it. I did notice that the 'gap' increases as the icon is further away from the right border.

Also, I didn't have this for a long time, i recently adjusted a bunch of things and then this suddenly happend.....:-(

Thnx in advance!

Comment: Actually, no we don't know what you mean when you say something is "missing". Please add a screen shot or something of what we are supposed to see. As far as I can tell, the menu is functioning properly.

Comment: Sorry for being so vague, I should have added a screen shot to be more clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix it you will need to apply "clear:both" to "#proxyMenu".

```
#proxyMenu {
    clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It appears to the the animation class firing on your #proxymenu when you open your menu.
See if you can remove the following style:

```
overflow: hidden
```